# Is it possible in checkstyle to validate javadoc on classes only if it's present

Tags: java, checkstyle

I would like checkstyle to validate javadoc on classes only if it is present, so no warnings that the javadoc is missing.

For javadoc on methods this is possible with the allowMissingJavadoc parameter, but I don't see an equivalent for the JavadocType module.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse with the Checkstyle plugin, do the following:

Edit you Checkstyle profile. Go to "Javadoc Comments", choose "Method Javadoc" and click "Open".
There you get a lot of options for the rule. Checking "allowMissingJavadoc" should do what you want.

If you are using Checkstyle without Eclipse this should be possible to configure too. I'm not familiar with it but this should give you a hint what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

> For javadoc on methods this is possible with the allowMissingJavadoc parameter, but I don't see an equivalent for the JavadocType module.

This isn't possible right now with the current Checkstyle. There is no such property for `JavadocType` (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocType) or any good, alternative method to achieve it.

I would suggest you file a feature request at https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/new to ask for it to be implemented.